# Swift: Setting SCNMaterial works for SCNBox but not for SCNGeometry loaded from Wings3D DAE

Tags: uiimage, swift, scenekit

This code excerpt (scene, camera, light, etc. cut out of the code) works in Swift on an iOS simulator:

```
    let boxNode = SCNNode()

    // Create a box
    boxNode.geometry = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0.1)
    let numFaces = 6

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

    // create and configure a material for each face
    var materials: [SCNMaterial] = Array()

    for i in 1...numFaces
    {
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "texture")
        materials += material
    }

    // set the material to the 3d object geometry
    boxNode.geometry.materials = materials
```

It generates a box with each face being the checkered image.

[image: SCNBox in App]

Trying the same thing with a simple stock geometry created in Wings3D, saved to a DAE, and loaded in the app gives me an appropriate shape, but no shading and image on the faces:

```
    let boxNode = SCNNode()

    // Load the geometry
    let urlToColladaFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Objects", withExtension:"dae")
    let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(URL:urlToColladaFile, options:nil)

    boxNode.geometry = sceneSource.entryWithIdentifier("dodecahedron3-0", withClass:SCNGeometry.self) as SCNGeometry
    let numFaces = 10

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

    // create and configure a material for each face
    var materials: [SCNMaterial] = Array()

    for i in 1...numFaces
    {
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "texture")
        materials += material
    }

    // set the material to the 3d object geometry
    boxNode.geometry.materials = materials
```

[image: Dodecahedron from Wings3D]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, mnuages & rickster.  Your deductions led me to researching my options within Wings3D, and I was able to solve the problem within Wings3D.

In short, I need to create a UV Mapping for each face of the solid.

For a regular polyhedra, I had multiple options:

- Select the whole body (and hence all of the faces), do a single UV Mapping of it, and have one image which was stretched over all of the faces.  There are online tutorials for how to do this.
- For each face, select it, do a UV Mapping (I typically chose Projection Normal to do it), and then each face will get the same mapping, no matter how many images you put into the materials array in my code.
- For each face, do the above first. Then go into the Outliner window, and duplicate the AUV (Automatic UV) file so that there is a unique one for each face.  Then select each AUV and assign it to a different face.  That would give me as many faces as I wanted, allowing me, for instance, to create a new image for each face of a die.  This I had to figure out -- there seems to be a one-to-one mapping of AUV mappings within Wings3D to what SceneKit calls Geometry Elements when setting the Materials.
- A combination of the above, so that multiple faces could share the same mapping and then be assigned the same image automatically.

This all becomes a little more complicated if I started adding bezels or smoother chamfers to the edges, for now I need to make sure that the UV Mapping makes sense for each set of faces I work on.  Again, there are tutorials on this on the web.

Thanks again!

Cheers,
Henry

Answer (score 6):

does your geometry have texture coordinates?
You can verify this programmatically (by checking if a source with the SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord semantic exists) or in the SceneKit editor built into Xcode.

Also note that you don't have to create one material per geometry element.
If they are all the same, just build an array of one material and it will be used for the entire geometry.

Comment: It appears that it does.  Adding this code:
    let sources  = boxNode.geometry.geometrySourcesForSemantic(SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord)  
        println("Texture Coordinates: \(sources.count) in \(sources)")  
          
        var k : Int = 0  
        for gs in sources  
        {  
            println("Source @\(k) has \(gs.vectorCount) Vectors")  
            k++  
        }  
  
  
Generates this in the console:  
  
**Texture Coordinates: 1 in [<SCNGeometrySource: 0x7ba360a0 | semantic=kGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord vectors=20 float2>]  
Source @0 has 20 Vectors**

Comment: (Argh -- apologies for only being given 5 minutes by the site to figure out markdown!) :-)

Comment: the geometry has texture coordinates, but they are all set to (0,0). Which is completely useless :)

`<float_array id="ID8-array" count="40">0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 </float_array>`

Comment: Yup. Zero texcoord at every vertex means you're seeing whatever is at the `0, 0` coordinate in the texture spread across the whole model -- that's the darker gray of the checkerboard pattern. You'll need to use the UV mapping features of whatever authoring tool you use, and make sure that it includes texcoords in DAE export.

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to define material when you design 3D Object.

then assign texture to each material programmatically.

```
 let material1 = SCNMaterial()
 material1.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "1")?.xFlipped
 material1.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

 let material2 = SCNMaterial()
 material2.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "2")?.xFlipped
 material2.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

 ...

 let material12 = SCNMaterial()
 material12.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "12")?.xFlipped
 material12.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true


 scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Dice", recursively: false)?.geometry?.materials = [material1, material2, material3, material4, material5, material6, material7, material8, material9, material10, material11, material12]
```

Where "Dice" is object identity name you set in property inspector.

```
extension UIImage {
    var xFlipped: UIImage {
        let tempImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height))
        tempImageView.image = self
        let viewTempImage = UIView(frame: tempImageView.frame)
        viewTempImage.addSubview(tempImageView)

        tempImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)
        let img = viewTempImage.screenshot

        return img

    }
}


extension UIView {
    var screenshot: UIImage{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        self.layer.renderInContext(context!)
        let screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return screenShot
    }
}
```

**Note:** In my case images when I add texture it was flipped horizontally. So I flipped manually like above.